# Anaconda Install Not Opening

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda, anaconda3

I have installed Anaconda on Linux through the terminal and it seems to install successfully but afterwards the anaconda-navigator command does not work and none of the conda commands. Also when I type in Python it brings up the version but doesn't mention Anaconda. I have tried this install on two separate machines and it gives me the same issue. What am I doing wrong to cause this?

This is what show's up for me after my install attempt:

```
[afraz@afraz-x220tester ~]$ sudo anaconda-navigator
[sudo] password for afraz: 
sudo: anaconda-navigator: command not found
[afraz@afraz-x220tester ~]$ python
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 24 2021, 12:50:35) 
[GCC 11.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

[Install in Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umfcb.png)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help! I will be trying it when I get home from work.

Answer (score 1):

**Any of the following approach should work for you:**

***Approach 1:***

Add anaconda installation path to .bashrc

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/USERNAME/anaconda3/bin"
```

Load in terminal

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Run from terminal

```
anaconda-navigator
```

***Approach 2:***

Activate conda

```
conda activate
```

Run from terminal

```
anaconda-navigator
```

***Approach 3:***

Activate conda root venv

```
source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root
```

Run from terminal

```
anaconda-navigator
```

***Approach 4:***

Create a new text document called "anaconda-navigator.desktop" in your home directory using terminal:

```
gedit anaconda-navigator.desktop
```

Edit the text file as following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Anaconda
Version=2.0
Type=Application
Exec=/path/to/anaconda-navigator
Icon=/path/to/selected/icon
Comment=Open Anaconda Navigator
Terminal=false
```

If you install Anaconda correctly then paths should be as following:

```
Exec=/home/USERNAME/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator
Icon=/home/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python-version/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/static/images/anaconda-icon-256x256.png
```

Save the file and move it to your local applications folder:

```
mv anaconda-navigator.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

Once this is done, you will be able to search for "Anaconda" in your applications.

This way you don't have to go through the terminal every time.

Comment: I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong everything is coming back as command not found. 
 Is it possible I have something else going on that's causing this?

Comment: I tried the first command and it came back as command not found then I tried the 3 other options and it came back as command not found for the conda, source, and gedit commands. Thanks again for taking the time to help, this is all new to me and I'm trying not to get overwhelmed.

Comment: Could you share the OS details??

Comment: I'm running Linux Manjaro I3wm and it's a fresh install.

Comment: Try this command `conda update anaconda-navigator`

Comment: It comes back with "sudo: conda: command not found"

Comment: I got it figured out, reinstalled Manjaro and retried the install it took this time and now Anaconda opens up with no problems. Thank you so much for all the suggestions and help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to PATH

in your terminal enter:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```